# Get parameter from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

In `data` from server I get the following JSON:

```
{
    "response": {
        "upload_url": "http:\/\/cs9458.vk.com\/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=6299927&aid=-14&gid=0&hash=73e525a1e2f4e6a0f5fb4c171d0fa3e5&rhash=bb38f2754c32af9252326317491a2c31&swfupload=1&api=1&wallphoto=1",
        "aid": -14,
        "mid": 6299927
    }
}
```

I need to get `upload_url`. I'm doing:

```
function (data) {
    var arrg = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data.upload_url);
});
```

but it doesn't work (alert doesn't show).

How do I get parameter `upload_url`?

Comment: Try `alert(arrg.response.upload_url)`

Comment: try `console.log(data.response.upload_url)` Also make sure you use dataType:"json" in your ajax call.

Comment: @MartyWallace SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

...Server", { uid: arr[1] }, function (data) { var arrg = JSON.parse(data); alert(a...

Comment: @Teop Lome - added my answer and explained a little more what you should be aware of. Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several correct answers here, but there is one trigger that decides how you should handle your returned data.

When you use an ajax request and use JSON data format, you can handle the data in two ways.

1. treat your data as JSON when it returns
2. configure your ajax call for JSON by adding a dataType

See the following examples:

**returned data string:**

```
{"color1":"green","color2":"red","color3":"blue"}
```

**ajax call without dataType:**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(data.color1); // renders green
        // do stuff 

    }
});
```

**ajax call with dataType:**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: "json", // added dataType
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.color1); // renders green
        // do stuff 
    }
});
```

In your case you probably used JSON.parse() when the call was already configured for JSON. Hope this makes things clear.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you need to access arrg, not data. Also you need to access the 'response' key first.

```
function (data) {
    var arrg = JSON.parse(data);
    alert( arrg.response.upload_url);
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

...Server", { uid: arr[1] }, function (data) { var arrg = JSON.parse(data); alert(a...

Comment: It's hard to suggest a fix when I can't see the whole code in question.

Comment: @TeopLome - that error tells you exactly what the problem is - you're trying to parse a string that isn't in JSON format. Drop the string in http://jsonlint.com and you'll see exactly where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

If response is in json and not a string then

```
alert(response.id);
```

or

```
alert(response['id']);
```

otherwise

```
var response = JSON.parse('{"id":"2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301"}');
response.id ; //# => 2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301
```

Comment: when i use `function (data) { var response = JSON.parse(data); alert(response.upload_url);});` i get `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a small error. try:

```
function (data) {
   var arrg = JSON.parse(data);
   alert(arrg.response.upload_url);
});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

...Server", { uid: arr[1] }, function (data) { var arrg = JSON.parse(data); alert(a...